# Fetching only one column from a table via where and select LINQ statement

Tags: c#, performance, entity-framework, ienumerable

I have written two queries which look like:

```
  var loggedUser2 = ctx.Users.Where(y => y.Email == User.Identity.Name).Select(usr => new Users { UserId = usr.UserId }).AsEnumerable();
```

And second query looks like this:

```
var loggedUser = ctx.Users.FirstOrDefault(y => y.Email == User.Identity.Name);
```

The second query noticabely takes much more time to pull a single record from a table from a remote server as I can tell.

For the first query I'm getting an error:

> The entity or complex type 'Users' cannot be constructed in a LINQ to Entities query.

when I try to access the property UserId of the "Users" object.

Now I have a couple of questions:

1. Why do I get this error and how do I actually access a property of a collection which is IEnumerable? I get it that I can materialize the query by using .ToList() and then have it accessed at [0].UserId, but I don't think this is the right way to do it?
2. What is the most efficient way to select a single column for a single records from a table (UserId in my case)? How would that query looks like (besides using a stored procedure).

Can someone help me out ? :)

Comment: In the `Select` in your first query: is `new Users` meant to  be `new User`?

Comment: @JSteward no, it's an existing record from DB, if this is what you mean ?

Comment: No I mean the `new Users` piece it seems odd to new up a class with plural name in the select. If however you meant to new up a new `User` that would make sense. So what exactly is the type `Users`?

Comment: @JSteward Users is a class generated from a DB... It's basically a DB class. But yes good point it's useless in my case to use a new operator in this one... I should just do: .select(y=>y.UserId).FirstOrDefault() ? But would it be a performance improvement over just using: FirstOrDefault(...) directly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can declare a DTO or you can use an anonymous type like this:

```
var user = ctx.Users
   .Where(u => u.Email == email)
   .Select(u => new { UserId = u.UserId })
   .FirstOrDefault()
```

Comment: Zdravko, thanks for the reply... How much performance improvement would this be over the second query, if at all ??

Comment: perf improvement - probably not much (in this case). having said that, there are other perfectly good reasons to select only what you are going to use.

Comment: Ah okay thanks zdravko... Which ones for example, could you just name a few? I'm trying to learn a few more things here that I can keep a note of :)

Comment: @User987 It saves memory (you create smaller objects), and also provides encapsulation (the recipient of your data doesn't know more than it needs to know about the data). As for speed, FirstOrDefault() and Where().FirstOrDefault() perform almost equally.